# complex join in scope in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, activerecord, join, scope

I have the following scope, which I know is not optimal:

```
scope :event_stream_for, lambda{ |user|
  where("target_id in (?) and target_type = ?", user.events.collect(&:id), "Event")
}
```

This creates 3 queries. How can I optimize it?

Alternatively, how do I put the whole sql statement in lambda of the scope, like

`SELECT * FROM activities WHERE target_type =='Event' AND target_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM events WHERE (host_id == user.id OR invitee_id == user.id))`

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming user has many events and each event belongs to a user.

```
scope :event_stream_for, lambda{ |user
  joins(:events). # or joins("LEFT JOIN events ON events.user_id = users.id").
  where(["target_type=?", "Event"]) 
}
```

this will run one query. Haven't tested my code with your table, but it should work similarly.

----------------------- based on your edited question -------------------

SELECT * FROM activities WHERE target_type =='Event' AND target_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM events WHERE (host_id == user.id OR invitee_id == user.id))

It's all about ActiveRecord Relation, http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast

```
Activity.
select("*,distinct events.id AS events_id").
joins("events ON (events.host_id = #{user.id} OR events.invitee_id = #{user.id}").
where(:target_type => 'Event')
```

Try this on console, and if it works you can just simply change it to scope.
Since i m not sure what you are trying to do, you may need some adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My user.events actually looks for events where events.host_id == user.id or events.invitee_id == user.id. Is there a Rails way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```rb
scope :event_stream_for, lambda{ |user|
  where("target_id in (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM events WHERE (host_id == ? OR invitee_id == ?) and target_type = ?", user.id, user.id, "Event")
}
```

It's just rearranging what you already had, but it should get you down to one query, since it doesn't use the associations in code.